# Workaround for provisional headers in Chromium

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp, tchromium

I´m using the CEF TChromium component and I´m seeing that Chromium is doing some stuff with the HTTP headers. I´ve seen this is [an open issue in the CEF project](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2136/devtools-network-inspector-provisional).

My problem is that this "Provisional headers" sent by the browser don´t have a session cookie.

Is there a way to tell Chromium not to strip the request headers?

Comment: The linked issue is about DevTools not refreshing the view after a request is sent. While DevTools displays it incorrectly, CEF is sending a different (perhaps correct) set of cookies. How do you know that the browser doesn't send a session cookie?

Comment: I don´t (and can´t) because I´m connecting to some external server over https, so I can´t see what the real traffic is.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to that server in Chrome and checking that it sends the session cookie using DevTools?

Comment: Yeah, tried that in Chrome and other browsers and the server sets a cookie after a login event.

Comment: In you CEF application can you see that the server is sending that same cookie after the login event?

Comment: Hi, Sergey, I solved the issue. It was about the HTTP headers I was sending but not the cookies, it was a problem of the server dropping requests because of the User-Agent. I changed the user agent to an accepted one and it worked.

Comment: Nice. It sounds like CEF TChromium was not a problem after all.